# Unix timestamp input for Symfony3 form

Tags: symfony, datetime

I have an Entity in Symfony3 which has a DateTime property called "checkin_at".

I would like to create a form where the input for checkin_at is a unix timestamp and it stores the corresponding DateTime for that timestamp.

E.g. I would enter 1498867201 and it would store 2017-07-01 00:00:01 i the entity.

I can't see how to get the DateTimeType field to accept a UNIX timestamp as a valid entry, or I can't figure out how to get the form to automatically convert NumberType to a DateTime for the entity.

Please advise :)

Comment: Use [data transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) to convert Unix Timestamp to DateTime. Anyway, wouldn't you prefer to have some sort of graphical date picker for GUI?

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a setter for the `checkin_at` variable?

in your entity you would add:

```
public function setCheckinAt(string $checkinAt){
 $this->checkinAt=date("Y-m-d H:m:s", $checkinAt);
}
```

you might refine your setter with more verification with Regex or `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;`  if you like

Comment: Or if you want to keep your original setter then you could use a data transformer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html